# Show that no application $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, of $C^k$ class, $k \geq 1$ can be injective

Tags: real-analysis, vector-analysis

How can I proof this:

> Show that no application $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, of $C^k$ class, $k \geq 1$ can be injective, i.e., there are $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $A \neq B$ and $f(A) = f(B)$ (Hint: show that given $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ in every open neighbourhood of $(a,b)$ there are points $(c,d),(c_1,d_1)$ where ${\partial}_1f(c,d) \neq 0$ or ${\partial}_1f(c_1,d_1) \neq 0$).

The problem is that I have no idea how to use the hint.

Thanks for all your comments.

Comment: '-1' Doesn't mention the _effort, source_ and any thoughts.

Comment: Nice question, I learned something from this one! +1!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $df =0$ everywhere, then $f(a, b)$ is constant and hence cannot be injective.  On the other hand, if at some point $(a_0, b_0) \in \Bbb R$ we have $df(a_0,  b_0) \ne 0$, we must also have

$f_a(a_0, b_0) = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial a}(a_0, b_0) \ne 0 \tag{1}$

or

$f_b(a_0, b_0) = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial b}(a_0, b_0) \ne 0. \tag{2}$

If (1) holds, then by the [*implicit function theorem*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem) there are open intervals $I, J \subset \Bbb R$ with $(a_0, b_0) \in I \times J$ and a function $g:J \to I$ such that $f(g(b), b) = f(a_0, b_0)$ for $b \in J$, with the corresponding result in the case that (2) applies.  Thus (1) leads to the conclusion that there is a continuum of points $(g(b), b) \in \Bbb R^2$, $b \in J$, for which $f(g(b), b) = f(a_0, b_0)$; $f$ cannot be injective under such circumstances; the analogous result with $f(a, g(a)) = f(a_0, b_0)$, $a \in I$,  follows from (2).  Thus we see that no $f \in C^k(\Bbb R^2, \Bbb R)$, $k \ge 1$, can be injective.  ***QED.***

***P.S.*** I don't quite get the hints myself.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 2):

You only need continuity of $f$. Asume such continuous inyective function exists.
Then 
$$g(t) := f(0,t)$$
$$h(t) := f(t,0)$$
are continuos inyective functions $\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ so they are strictly monotone and wlog both strictly increasing and $h(1)<g(1)$. Notice that $$h(1)>h(0) = f(0,0) = g(0)$$ so, by intermediate value theorem, there exists $c \in (0,1)$ such that $$g(c) = h(1)$$
and hence 
$$f(0,c) = f(1,0)$$
that is a contradiction.

Comment: Why is $h(1) < g{1}$?

Comment: @RobertLewis wlog, otherwise $g(1)<h(1)$ and the proof is identical.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot quite make out what the hint is saying.  But how about this?  First argue that without loss of generality, we may suppose there exists $(a,b)$ such that $\partial_1 f(a,b) > 0$.  Then argue that there exist $a_1 < a < a_2$ such that $f(a_1,b) < f(a,b) < f(a_2,b)$ (think of $a_1$ and $a_2$ as being sufficiently close to $a$).  Now there is a continuous path from $(a_1,b)$ to $(a_2,b)$ that does not pass through $(a,b)$.  Apply the intermediate value theorem to $f$ evaluated along this path.

Note that this is in essence Dini's original proof of the implicit function theorem.  I just attended a seminar about it a few days ago.

Comment: Note also if you replace the intermediate value theorem by the mean value theorem, then you only need that $f$ is differentiable - the derivative doesn't need to be continuous.  Apparently this is Young's generalization of Dini's implicit function theorem.